# How can I have different LINQ to XML queries based on two different condition?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

We want the query result should be assigned with two results based on some condition like following:

```
var vAudioData = (from xAudioinfo in xResponse.Descendants(ns + "DIDL-Lite").Elements(ns + "item")

if((xAudioinfo.Element(upnp + "artist")!=null)
{
   select new RMSMedia
     {
        strAudioTitle = ((string)xAudioinfo.Element(dc + "title")).Trim()
     };
}
else
   select new RMSMedia
      {
         strGen = ((string)xAudioinfo.Element(dc + "Gen")).Trim()
      };
```

The VarAudioData should contain both if and else condition values.

I have added the if condition just to project , what is my needs, m quite sure though that we can not use if and else.

Please help if there are any other approach to accomplish this.

Thanks,

Subhen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from xAudioinfo in xResponse.Descendants(ns + "DIDL-Lite").Elements(ns + "item")
select new RSMedia
{
   strAudioTitle = (xAudioinfo.Element(upnp + "artist") != null) 
      ? ((string)xAudioinfo.Element(dc + "title")).Trim()
      : null,
   strGen = (xAudioinfo.Element(upnp + "artist") == null) 
      ? ((string)xAudioinfo.Element(dc + "Gen")).Trim()
      : null
}
```

You could also utilize a union, which may look a little nicer... this is just as effective though.